# How can I read and use url from an online file in dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, sh

I'm trying to create a `Dockerfile` that read some URLs from an online file but when I try to use `wget` with the URL in a variable, it fails. If I print the variables in a console message the result is the corrects URLs.

If the variables are declared with ENV or initialized with the URL I don't have problems to use it in the `wget`; the problem only happens when reading URLs from a file.

```
FROM openjdk:8

USER root
RUN mkdir /opt/tools /aplicaciones /deployments \
    && wget -q "www.url_online_file.com" -O url.txt \
    && while IFS== read -r name url; do if [ $name = "url1" ]; then export URL1=$url; fi; if [ $name = "url2" ]; then export URL2=$url; fi; done < url.txt \
    && echo "DEBUG URL1=$URL1"; echo "DEBUG URL2=$URL2"; \
    && wget -q $URL1 -O url1.zip
```

Error:

```
DEBUG URL1=www.prueba1.com
DEBUG URL2=www.prueba2.com
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir /opt/tools /aplicaciones /deployments     && wget -q "www.url_online_file.com" -O url.txt     && while IFS== read -r name url; do if [ $name = "url1" ]; then export URL1=$url; fi; if [ $name = "url2" ]; then export URL2=$url; fi; done < url.txt  && echo "DEBUG URL1=$URL1"; echo "DEBUG URL2=$URL2";     && wget -q $URL1 -O url1.zip' returned a non-zero code: 8
```

The file.txt structure in online_file is:

```
url1=www.prueba1.com
url2=www.prueba2.com
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], probably without Docker involved at all. Do you really only want to extract the last URL from the file? The `export` is superfluous here. The simplest explanation is if the URL is invalid; the other commands here can't really produce that error.

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html says exit code 8 means the server returned an error response. Is your real URL invalid?

Comment: `wget -qO - "www.url_online_file.com" | while read -r name url; do case $name in "url1") url1=$url; wget -q "$url" -O url1.zip;; "url2") url2=$url;; esac; echo "DEBUG url1=$url1 url2=$url2"; done` would avoid the temporary file and attempt to fetch all url1 instances.

Comment: The main goal of that dockerfile is update to older version. In the older version the urls were in the wget command. So now I'm try to read all urls from another file to doesn't update all the dockerfiles if one url change in the future.

Comment: The url are the same tha was in the other file and if I copy paste in an ENV declaration works.

Comment: When I try to put the wget command inside the while loop it doesn't download the file in the url.
`
Archive:  url1.zip
[91m  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of url1.zip or
        url1.zip.zip, and cannot find url1.zip.ZIP, period.
[0mThe command '[...]' returned a non-zero code: 9
`

Comment: That looks like an unrelated problem. Again, your question doesn't contain enough information to troubleshoot this, and the `Dockerfile` adds unrelated complications. Troubleshoot your shell script in isolation, then figure out how to put it in a `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was used the command `wget -i` to the www.url_online_file.com and modified the content of the file to:

```
www.prueba1.com
www.prueba2.com
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

USER root
RUN mkdir /opt/tools /aplicaciones /deployments \
    && wget -i "www.url_online_file.com" \
    && && rm url* \
    && mv url1* url1.zip \
    && mv url2* url2.zip \
    && unzip url1.zip -d /opt/tools \
    && unzip url2.zip -d /opt/tools \
    && rm url1.zip \
    && rm url2.zip
```